# Binding Command lost

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a control (a) that needs to show / hide another control (b) in it

(a) Has:

1- A reference to (b)

2- A dependency property for (b) viewmodel

(b) Has a Dependency property for its viewmodel Named **ViewModel**.

Here is the code:
For (a)

If I create that way All mi binds works pretty well, my problem is if I have many instances of (a), each one works as b is the same instance for all of them because it is a static property.

```
public partial class a : UserControl
{ 
    public a()
    {

    }

    public bVM b
    {
        get { return (bVM)GetValue(bProperty); }
        set { SetValue(bProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty bProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("b", typeof(bVM), typeof(a)), new PropertyMetadata(new bVM()));        
}
```

now if I create a bVM instance into (a) constructor, all my binds work fine except for **command bindings**.

```
public partial class a : UserControl
{ 
    public a()
    {
        b = new bVM();
    }

    public bVM b
    {
        get { return (bVM)GetValue(bProperty); }
        set { SetValue(bProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty bProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("b", typeof(bVM), typeof(a));        
}
```

And here is my bind for (b) at (a) xaml:

```
<local:b
    x:Name="bName"
    ViewModel="{Binding ElementName=ThisAControl,Path=b}"/>
```

And this is my bind for command lost

```
<Button Content="Test" 
   Command="{BindingElementName=ThisBControl,Path=ViewModel.ExitCommand }" />
```

Why my command binds are lost second way?
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't create a dependency property for a view model. The view model should be set as a `DataContext` of the view.

Comment: :( Well Think must read more about it, Tks for your time.

Comment: "has a Dependency property for its viewmodel Named ViewModel." that's where you screwed yourself.  Your user controls should be developed like regular controls. It's fine to place their logic in their codebehind.  Does a TextBox have a TextBoxViewModel?  Nope.  It has a public DP called Text which is mapped to the text you see in the UI.

Comment: @Will That's a good picture Of what I'm doing wrong :( Tks.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @dymanoid comment, that normally you should not have a dependency property for VM. Aside of this strange implementation, technically the reason why binding is lost is because in constructor you are breaking it with:
`b = new bVM();`
To set value for a dependency property inside dependency object you should you [SetCurrentValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) method, that will not break any binding.
`SetCurrentValue(a.bProperty, new bVM());`

> *MSDN:*
>   The SetCurrentValue method changes the effective value of the property, but existing triggers, **data bindings**, and styles will continue to work.

Comment: Tks for your answer,  I'm going to polish my implementation, but my bigest question was answered by you :).. I love stack overflow